# Why is Ruby 1.8.6 RC1 more recent than Ruby 1.8.6 Final?

Tags: windows, ruby

Getting to the Ruby One-click installer for Windows, we may go to

> http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

and then

> http://rubyinstaller.org/download.html

however over there, it seems that

> Ruby 1.8.6 RC1 (patchlevel 383)

is actually more recent than

> Ruby 1.8.6 RC2 (patchlevel 27)

or

> Ruby 1.8.6 Final (patchlevel 26)

If I install them on different machines, the RC1 actually shows a more recent date than RC2 or Final, by using

```
ruby -v
```

What's the rule?  Does it go strictly by patchlevel?  That is, the patchlevel decides how update it is, instead of whether it is RC1, RC2, or Final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby-Lang website advertise a package of Ruby for Windows called One-Click Installer.

That installer used to have their own version schema, as you note with `186-26` or `186-27 RC2`

On RubyForge website (news section) you will find that efforts of the project as moved towards newer RubyInstaller packages, and is indicated there and the RubyInstaller download page that `186-27 RC2` is part of the legacy versions.

Latest RubyInstaller (currently in Release Candidate attempts) provide information of the correct Ruby version that includes and install, as indicated by the version string `1.8.6-p383` which is patchlevel 383 of Ruby.

Please note that you're comparing different type of packages. One-Click Installer versus RubyInstaller.

You can read more about this in the [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller) and the latest announcement [at RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=35591)

Hope this answer your questions.

Comment: Exactly. The One-Click Installer and the RubyInstaller are two different packages with different version schemas.

Answer (score 0):

The RC numbers are release candidate numbers of the installer (and any Win32 modifications of Ruby, but I think those are all upstream). Ruby's own version number is 1.8.6 + the patchlevel.

Comment: so you mean the version number and the patchlevel is the sole indicator of how update it is?

Comment: Yes. Version number is the only thing that determines program compatibility, the patchlevel describes bugginess in the APIs, and the RC number describes bugginess of the installer (and possibly the windows execution environment.)